# How to explore all file of windows phone in desktop PC?

Tags: 8.0, 8.1, storage, 8.1-update-1, usb

The application [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) allows the apple product users to view all their files and folders **(even the root folders and etc.)** of iPhone/iPad/iPod in desktop(either in windows or mac) machine. Here you can see the sample screenshot.

[image]

Even [Windows Phone Device Manager](http://touchxperience.com/windows-phone-device-manager/) is allowing to view windows phone 7 files and folders.

[image]

**Similarly, Is there any software available for Windows Phone 8/8.1 which allows to view all files in desktop?**

Comment: Not without hacking the phone a bit. There are hacks for Samsung, Nokia, and Huawei phones (maybe also for others) that will change the MTP (the protocol used for accessing the phone over USB) root location. If you want full access, you also need to increase the MTP service's privileges; by default, it runs as a limited account that can read part of the file system but not all of it, and can only write to a few places.

Comment: @CBHacking The question was asked more than a year ago and now I'm completely out of it. But anyways thanks for your comments. This may help me in future when I work on Windows 10 mobile. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 7):

It's not currently possible to browse the complete file system of a Windows Phone 8.

When connected via USB, only the Pictures, Video and Music are exposed via Windows Explorer

Answer (score 3):

Yes It is possible but you need to unlock your phone. Download and install Interop tools and then open the app and tick down the **Full FileSystem Access**. Then restart your phone and connect to PC. You will have the full access now.

[image]

Comment: I had asked this question 3 years ago and now I am not into this anymore, and I guess your solution is specifically for Lumias. Anyways thanks for your solution, it might help others.

Answer (score 2):

[Sharefolder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/sharefolder-explorer/9wzdncrdmmtk) is the name of the utility.

But it is available in limited territory.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the "Windows Phone app for desktop"?
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=265472

Once installed, it allows you to browse the files on your device. - Just remember to type in your unlock pin on the phone before you try this.

Comment: Of-course I did. It is just showing only the music, photos, videos and pod casts but not the other files/folders. I want to see even the root folders too like Application Data, Windows folder, etc.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I'd misread your question.- Possibly because your example images were of documents, spreadsheets and mp3s.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no app on Windows that can open System files of Windows phone 8.1. However if you can connect your phone to a PC running **Linux** you can get access to **some(not all)** of the system files.

Comment: The question was asked more than a year ago and now I'm completely out of it. But anyways thanks for your comments. This may help me in future. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @HariDev Yes. I answered this question as this may help others looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Two utilises that help you gain system level access (including the registry) are [Root Tool (pulled from Windows Store last year, but available in link)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-phone-8/general/root-tool-beta-testing-t3006051) and [WP internals](http://www.wpinternals.net/), but they are somewhat limited in functionality and model support.