# Nokia Lumia 830 and interop guide

Tags: 8.1, lumia

I'm a complete noob when it comes to smartphones - I just recently bought my very first one, the Nokia Lumia 830 (the only reason I'd never had a smartphone before was that I found the operating systems utterly obnoxious... until I got to see WP and decided to give it a go).

Basically the only thing that has really thrown me off thus far are the ads. Googling for possible solutions has led me to [this guide](http://phoneprouser.com/how-to-block-all-ads-on-nokia-and-microsoft-lumia-phones/1215/), but unfortunately the download links are dead there and I'm too much of a smartphone noob to find some working ones for my model.

Then I found something [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3123/how-to-explore-all-file-of-windows-phone-in-desktop-pc/), and figured this would be a good place to ask for help.

Could someone please give me a link to the right version app and walk me through anything that either of the first two links doesn't cover? I really hate ads...

My phone's specs are:
Nokia Lumia 830, Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2 (version 8.10.15148.160), hardware version 1.0.0.0.

(sorry about misleading tags, but not enough reputation to post more accurate ones...)

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to solve here? Which ads?

Comment: According to my research, the only way to have a working adblock on WP 8.1 is to remove ads altogether by accessing and editing the phone's hosts files, which I cannot do without a rootkit. If that info is incorrect, I'd appreciate a work-around. 

Though I've noticed cool stuff can be done with interop anyway, so I'd like to have it regardless of possible other solutions. I hope it's clear now.

The instruction links from my OP should clarify more, if that's not enough.

Comment: @AnOrc The guide link you provided points to a dictionary and not a guide.

Comment: Wow, it does indeed. My bad. It's fixed now. Apologies! I'll put it in this comment as well: http://phoneprouser.com/how-to-block-all-ads-on-nokia-and-microsoft-lumia-phones/1215/

Answer (score 0):

You should follow [this instruction](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=691304&st=620#entry51115465) (russian speak).

I shall try to translate it on English. Most likely, it will be so scarry.

1. Enable "Developer's mode" on Lumia.
2. Download and install file on [this link](http://4pda.ru/forum/dl/post/8369438/InteropToolsApp.zip). This is those "right version".
3. Go to Parameteers - Adds - Interop Tools (not sure that I correcly described names in system menu of english smartphones, i have ciryllic version. So, **Adds** is the last item in main system munu).
4. Find **Unlock** -- Interop Unlock.
5. Change the next items:

   - **interop unlock** - on;
   - **new capability engine unlock** - on;
   - **full filesystem unlock**   on;
   - for **your phone model** - restore NDTKSvc.

You may also find more usefull things about Interop tools instaling [enter link description here](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=691304)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Was hoping for some clues in English at first, but I've decided to give your links a go. I'm much obliged, but the download links do not work - 404 on both the direct link you provided and on the link within the instructions you gave me (it's the same address). Tried with and without VPN just to be sure. Would you be so kind and post a working one?

Comment: _the download links do not work_  - you need to register at the 4pda.ru to get file on this link. It will not had been shown until your don't loged in.

Comment: Registering on that site requires me to pass a captcha test in Cyrillic... can't do that, I'm afraid... any other link?

Could you also post a screenshot of what you mean in your point 3.? Sorry, I don't see "adds" or anything alike anywhere.

Comment: This is [file](https://yadi.sk/d/uIB_QpR93YrwY2) from 4pda.